# Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token < , ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
<script>
    (function(){
        var searchURL = 'http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/search';
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: searchURL,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache: false,
                async:false,
                success: function(responseData, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                        iframe(responseData);
                    }
            });
    })();
    </script>
```

I added this script to my html file and it is show the following errors, copy pasting the function in console is also showing the same errors.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < 
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

could anyone help me resolve this issue, I am using Chrome brower.

Comment: You're requesting `jsonp`, but receiving HTML. The `jsonp` isn't a magic solution that lets you get any data from any domain. The response needs to be a `jsonp` response.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/search does not render data in JSONP format. It is just an HTML page. So when trying to parse the HTML as JSON, you're getting an error because the first character is a <. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: is there any alternate way we can get data from wiktionary using js

Comment: This is asked fairly frequently. I'd suggest searching for how to get data from a different domain. Ultimately, if there's no server-side support for cross-domain requests, you'll need a proxy to make the request for you.

Comment: You should probably have a look at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats

Comment: Thanks @Jraede, understood what the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't request arbitrary pages via AJAX, and jsonp doesn't magically make that work.  You need to use the [Wiktionary API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).

The URL is `http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',  // will automatically add "?callback=jqueryXXX"
    cache: true,  // the API complains about the extra parameter
    data: {  // the parameters to add to the request
        format: 'json',
        action: 'query',
        titles: 'test'
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```